# Fatal Error: Object scala not found

Tags: scala

I just installed scala via macports on osx

sudo port install scala28

I created a simple script called test.scala

```
println("hello world")
```

when I run it via

scala test.scala

I get the following error:

```
scala test.scala 
error: fatal error: object scala not found.
one error found
```

any ideas?

** UPDATE ** 
Running from the REPL yields the correct results but still unable to use "scala" directly

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.8.1.final (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_24).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :load ./test.scala
Loading ./test.scala...
hi there sir

scala>
```

** UPDATE FINAL **

when I did ps -ef | grep scala 
I had a couple scala compile servers running, when I shut those down and re-ran my script all was working again. Must have been in a bad state.

Comment: This sounds like a classpath issue. What happens when you try to compile something with `scalac`?

Comment: well, why not accept the answer? it worked nicely for me...

Answer (score 7):

appeared to be FSC in a bad state, restarted the FSC compiler