# wordcount.scala error

Tags: macos, scala, scalding

I installed scalding on my mac with OSX Lion. When I run the word count.scala program to test the installation, I get the following error message:

```
scalac -classpath /var/folders/_j/_7d75_hj79133bcm7xrqzvz80000gn/T/maven/hadoop-core-0.20.2.jar:/var/folders/_j/_7d75_hj79133bcm7xrqzvz80000gn/T/maven/log4j-1.2.15.jar:/var/folders/_j/_7d75_hj79133bcm7xrqzvz80000gn/T/maven/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/var/folders/_j/_7d75_hj79133bcm7xrqzvz80000gn/T/maven/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/var/folders/_j/_7d75_hj79133bcm7xrqzvz80000gn/T/maven/zookeeper-3.3.4.jar:/Users/BessonPascal/Desktop/scalding/target/scalding-assembly-0.8.0.jar: -d /var/folders/_j/_7d75_hj79133bcm7xrqzvz80000gn/T/script-build /Users/BessonPascal/Desktop/wordCount.scala
error: scala.tools.nsc.MissingRequirementError: object scala not found.
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.getModuleOrClass(Definitions.scala:655)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.getModule(Definitions.scala:605)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.ScalaPackage(Definitions.scala:145)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.ScalaPackageClass(Definitions.scala:146)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.AnyClass(Definitions.scala:176)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.init(Definitions.scala:814)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.<init>(Global.scala:697)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Main$.process(Main.scala:105)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Main$.main(Main.scala:123)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Main.main(Main.scala)

error: fatal error: object scala not found.
```

Comment: Have you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395470/fatal-error-object-scala-not-found

Comment: I did but it didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple other versions of WordCount in Scalding, which I've run on OSX.
The build is based on Gradle (must be 1.3 or later)

https://github.com/Cascading/Impatient/tree/master/part8

The `build.gradle` script shows how to pull matching versions of required libraries from the different Maven repos.

So far, I've found Gradle or Maven to be more stable for this than SBT -- at least if you're trying to run in "--hdfs-local" for Hadoop Standalone and produce "fat jars" to run on a remote Hadoop cluster.